# MySQL fill out the second table with data from the first table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null, sql-update

There are two tables in the MySQL db:

```
Dictionary Table:
**item | description**
--------------------
item1 | Description1
item2 | Description2
........
item1000000 | Description1000000


**Unknown**:
**item | description**
--------------------
item33 | NULL
item1234 | NULL
item8599 | NULL
```

I need to fill out the description column of `Unknown` table by the correspondent data of `Dictionary` table.

**How to make it with one query?**

So the result would be

```
item | description
--------------------
item33 | Description33
item1234 | Description1234
item8599 | Description8599
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to join the tables:

```
UPDATE Unknown JOIN Dictionary USING (item)
SET    Unknown.description = Dictionary.description
```

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I see that's the SELECT. I need to UPDATE the second table.

Comment: @Haradzieniec: Your question wasn't clear.  See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Update` with a `Join`:

```
update unknown u 
join dictionary d on u.item = d.item
set u.description = d.description
```